# Confusing Python version

Tags: python

On my Mac OS X Lion, I type the following in Terminal:

```
hobbes3@hobbes3:~$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
hobbes3@hobbes3:~$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^D
hobbes3@hobbes3:~$ /usr/local/bin/python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Feb 23 2012, 00:05:44) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Part of my `/usr/local/bin/` looks like this:

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    32B Feb 23 00:07 pydoc -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.2/bin/pydoc
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    33B Feb 23 00:07 python -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.2/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    40B Feb 23 00:07 python-config -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.2/bin/python-config
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    36B Feb 23 00:07 python2.7 -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.2/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    43B Feb 23 00:07 python2.7-config -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.2/bin/python2.7-config
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    34B Feb 23 00:07 pythonw -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.2/bin/pythonw
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    37B Feb 23 00:07 pythonw2.7 -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.2/bin/pythonw2.7
```

Why is it that the first time I type `python` I get v2.7.1, but when I type the full path `/usr/local/bin/python` I get v2.7.2?

I installed v2.7.2 using homebrew, and I would like to use that version because I believe my Django is installed under v2.7.2 python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because poor bash is confused. Clear `python`'s hash entry.

```
hash -d python
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked great.

I also have a symbolic link that makes `/usr/local/bin/vi` follow `/usr/local/bin/mvim` which is MacVim, a GUI Vim for Mac. But typing `hash -d vi` didn't work. Typing `vi` still gives me the default vi. Any idea on this as well?

Comment: Similarly `which vi` gives `/usr/local/bin/vi`, so it sounds like the same problem. `ls -l` on `/usr/local/bin/` gives `lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    19B Feb  9 23:32 vi -> /usr/local/bin/mvim`

Comment: Just do a `rehash`, which will rebuild the entire hash table from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell the reason they are different is because you're calling them differently.

- `$ python` asks the system for the default version of python. This is the same as doing `env python`. Typically if you ran `which python` it would show you the path to what it would run.
- `$ /usr/local/bin/python` executed the thing at that path

Most unix like OS's have have a concept similar to "Alternatives" in linux ("Ports" on some BSD's). That's where the system default interpreter for a language is defined.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846167/how-to-change-default-python-version will give you a basis on how to change it.